# extract values from an array that contain key and values separated by any symbol like ,

Tags: php

I have an array like below all values are dynamically generated

```
array(      
[education_provider_state]=>Arunanchal Pradesh,Assam        
[e_p_coeducational_type]=>Co-Ed,Girls       
)
```

i want output like

```
array(      
[education_provider_state]=>array([0]=>Arunanchal Pradesh[1]=>Assam         
[e_p_coeducational_type]=>array([0]=>Co-Ed[1]=>Girls        
)
```

I want to get the values of key and values of corresponding key.
How can I achieve this Please somebody help me . Thank You

Comment: `foreach($myArray as $key => $value) { ... }`

Comment: Post your expected output as from your question it seems you simply need to use `foreach` loop over here

Comment: @ Mark Baker I want generate this values with same approach that you suggested sir but my problem is this that I want to get the values of key and all values that is come after "," of corresponding key

Comment: @ Uchiha I had edit my question kindly see this.

Comment: `foreach($myArray as $key => $subArray) { foreach($subArray as $value) { echo $key, ' contains ', $value, PHP_EOL; } }`

Comment: @ **Mark** sorry to say that this code didn't work for me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `array_map` along with the `explode` like as

```
print_R(array_map(function($v){ return explode(',',$v);},$arr));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [education_provider_state] => Array
        (
            [0] => Arunanchal Pradesh
            [1] => Assam
        )

    [e_p_coeducational_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => Co-Ed
            [1] => Girls
        )

)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/462831)

Comment: You're Welcome. Gald it helped you. _(FYI: You can accept an answer or upvote an answer which really helps you.)_

Comment: sir i don't know how to accept the answer and i don't have enough reputation for up voting . I did try before

Comment: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
   echo "This is my $key and this is my $value\n";
}
```